# Reading TXT Lines into Character

Tags: c++

I'm completely out of ideas right now. Basically, I want to read parts of a line in a text file, but this code is not working, and I have no idea why:

```
        char temp_char  = '\0';
        char _char = '\0';
        while(1)
        {
            _places.get(temp_char);
            if(temp_char == '\t')
                break;

            _char += temp_char;

            cout << _char;
        }
```

Basically, it's supposed to read from the start of the file until it comes into contact with a tab character. Unfortunately, it never stops, and _char comes out as a ton of random characters that make no sense.

I've looked over the TXT file, and it's the correct encoding and all, and the tab is a normal tab character in the file, but for whatever reason I can't read it from the stream using either get or >>.

I've been experimenting for an hour now, looked over numerous websites for help, and I've gotten nowhere... all this is doing is stressing me out...

Edit: I can also provide the rest of the program code if this isn't the problem, but it should be. :/

Here is where the file is opened:

```
                ifstream _places;
                _places.open("ECC.txt");
                if (_places.fail())
                {
                    cout << "Could not load text file, please make sure ECC.txt is in the same folder.";
                    _getch();
                    exit(1);
                }
```

Comment: Why are you doing a '+=' on the _char, is that a std::string? What is _places? Can you post the code where you are opening the file. Is the stream still good?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't want to see the rest of the program. We want to see the rest of a trivially-small program that replicates the error. See http://sscce.org/. for tips.

Comment: You say that the text file "is the correct encoding", but which one do you think is *correct*? What encoding are you using? And which platform are you compiling the code on?

Comment: @Cody Gray I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2010 to compile and ANSI encoding on the file I'm trying to open.

Comment: @KevSana: Information like that goes in the question, not the comments.  Comments can be and are deleted without warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, is _char a std::string, char[] or a char* ?

Secondly, I would have used either

```
temp_char = _places.get()
```

or

```
std::string temp;
getline(_places,temp)
for (unsigned int i=0; i<temp.size(), ++i)
    if (temp[i] == '\t')
        break;
    _char += temp[i] // assuming, and REALLY HOPING _char is a std::string
```

Be careful with the get() methods from the ifstream, when they can return the int.

Comment: Ah, I was using _char as just char, but that doesn't seem to have been working correctly. Switching _char to a string and switching:
_places.get(temp_char);
with
temp_char = _places.get()
Worked perfectly.

Though, the reason I was using _char as a char was so that I could turn it into an int.

Comment: As you know, char is only one character. Saying char c = char+char makes no sense. If you want to convert it to an int, you can either use atoi() for getting the intvalue (makes '4' to 4) or simply int(char) for getting the ASCII value. Are your problem solved, or is there anything more to it? If it is, please edit your question :)

Comment: Actually that did answer my question, thanks! I think I've got enough to finish my project now. ^_^